# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagClass' of undefined in Node js

Tags: node.js, typeerror, pem, p12

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
//some code here

var keyFile = fs.readFileSync('./test.p12', 'binary');
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(keyFile);
var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1,false, employeeID);
var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});
var cert = bags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
var msg = {
type: 'CERTIFICATE',
body: forge.asn1.toDer(asn1.cert).getBytes()
};
var pem = forge.pem.encode(msg);
```

I am trying to read certificate,RSA private key and publick key from p12 file. This is the code i have written in Node js, but getting TypeError.

Comment: it is body: forge.asn1.toDer(cert.asn1).getBytes()

Comment: the code what you have pasted doesn't have the name `tagClass`, so your error is in some other part of ur code. So post your fullcode

Comment: `tagClass` is reading from `asn1.js`, This file i think it comes with the node-forge package. Code in asn1.js is like below                           
  ` /**
 * Converts the given asn1 object to a buffer of bytes in DER format.
 *
 * @param asn1 the asn1 object to convert to bytes.
 *
 * @return the buffer of bytes.
 */
asn1.toDer = function(obj) {
  var bytes = forge.util.createBuffer();

  // build the first byte
  var b1 = obj.tagClass | obj.type; '